# Gaining reputation through comments

Tags: feature-request

As far as I am aware it is not possible to gain reputation through having one your comments up-voted.

This seems strange as some comments I have seen are as good at answering a question, as the best answer itself.

If this is the case could gaining reputation changes happen through votes on comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is: comments are not supposed to be answers; answers are. Comments should be used to give remarks about the question or request additional information. They should be used to guide users, e.g. give pointers to the OP how to rephrase the question to make it easier to understand and answer. Of course there are examples when questions are de facto answered using comments. Still that would not be the *right way* to go.

See: [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and [Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette)

If you really intend to go through with this feature request, RaspberryPi meta is not the right place. That's would be a network wide issue to be placed on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com). I, however, doubt you'll get much support on this.

Comment: The thing is some comments are really good at pointing something out, where an answer is perhaps not appropriate. So it seems a shame nothing is gained through really good thought provoking comments.

Comment: As someone who writes *a lot* of comments -- some of which are even genuinely helpful -- I think this is fair enough, since part of what it does is *discourage* people from using comments instead of answers.  If you have an answer and time to write it out, do that.  I often leave comments when I know the hints the OP needs but I simply don't have time to write what I would consider a full fledged answer (sometimes my hope is this will actually confirm/remind someone who does have time to write an answer, and the person who puts that effort in should get the points).

Comment: I'll upvote that comment that should be an answer ;)